# Ruby Conditional argument to method

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, conditional-attribute

I have some 'generic' methods that extract data based on css selectors that usually are the same in many websites. However I have another method that accept as argument the css selector for a given website.

I need to call the get_title method if title_selector argument is nos passed. How can I do that?

## Scrape that accept css selectors as arguments

```
  def scrape(urls, item_selector, title_selector, price_selector,     image_selector)
    collection = []
    urls.each do |url|
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read) # Opens URL
      @items = doc.css(item_selector)[0..1].map {|item| item['href']} # Sets items
      @items.each do  |item| # Donwload each link and parse
        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(item).read)
        collection << {
          :title   => page.css(title_selector).text, # I guess I need conditional here 
          :price  => page.css(price_selector).text
        }
      end
      @collection = collection
    end
  end
```

## Generic title extractor

```
  def get_title(doc)
    if doc.at_css("meta[property='og:title']")
      title = doc.css("meta[property='og:title']")
    else doc.css('title')
      title = doc.at_css('title').text
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `or` operator inside your `page.css` call. It will call `get_title` if `title_selector` is falsey (nil).

```
:title => page.css(title_selector || get_title(doc)).text,
```

I'm not sure what `doc` should actually be in this context, though.

**EDIT**

Given your comment below, I think you can just refactor `get_title` to handle all of the logic. Allow `get_title` to take an optional `title_selector` parameter and add this line to the top of your method:

```
return doc.css(title_selector).text if title_selector
```

Then, my original line becomes:

```
:title => get_title(page, title_selector)
```

Comment: Careful. `.text` is only called on one of those, and one is `css`, the other `at_css`.

Comment: Mmm, I guess I didn't explain well. Argument inside page.css() is a css selector like '#title > .title-class > h1'. So get_title(doc) inside this wont work because get_title return a scraped title page ('Amazon.com ...)not a .css selector. FYI doc = full html source in Nokogiri format. Thks.

Comment: Ah, your explanation was fine. My reading comprehension was lacking. I *think* my edit should cover it now.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is perfect.